# How do I unscrew a stuck cartridge from faucet?

Tags: plumbing, screws, plumbing-fixture, stuck, cartridge

how do I unscrew  the cartridge for my double faucet? It’s stuck and spraying boiling water and vinegar in it didn’t help. I'm trying to fix a leaky tap (hot water leaks). This seems to be the issue.

- Type: American Standard
- Model Number: 2904.222

[image: picture of cartridge]

Comment: @ruskes can you refer me to a YouTube video? Would like to DIY it myself

Comment: sorry, i do not know of youtube video.yes you can diy that

Answer (score 2):

Here's the YouTube video from American Standard, which shows using a wrench on the cartridge flats to unscrew it:

You may need to apply a lot of leverage, so an open-ended or even closed-ended wrench that matches the size of the flats is they way to go if its stuck, perhaps with a cheater bar. You can also apply a bit of a "penetrating oil" where the green corrosion is showing; just remember to wipe out the inside once you've removed the old cartridge and before you put the new one in.

[American Standard faucet cartridge removal youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wA7aLHZ84D4)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends where it leaks.

In any case first you have to remove the large silver color metal covering it on both sides.

For that you have to also remove the middle part and the right side valve handle.

Now pull it up and it will expose the large nuts holding the cartridge. Unscrew and repair or replace the two seals.